# For the first time app is in portrait mode,if the device is in landscape mode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

In our app for the first time our app is in portrait mode.
if the device is in landscape ,it will show the Portrait screen mode.why?
but When i manually rotate the simulator then it will go in Landscape and Portrait mode properly.
but for the first time the simulator show the portrait screen..
please solve my trouble that why this is happen or how to solved it..

Comment: "lease solve my trouble that why this is happen or how to solved it.." Sure thing buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add supported orientations to your app in Xcode.

[image]

If that doesn't work try adding this to your viewController

**NOTE:** This code says that the app supports every orientation except `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` when the device is an iPhone or iPod Touch, and can be modified to suit specific orientation requirements for when the device is and iPhone/iPad.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```